# How to enable wdio.ps1 file script in nodejs

Tags: node-modules

When we run the ./node_modules/.bin/wdio config this command on vsc editor it gives this error. Please tell me how to resolve this.

./node_modules/.bin/wdio : File C:\Users\JB\workspace\webdriver-io-prtactice\node_modules.bin\wdio.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For
more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- ./node_modules/.bin/wdio config
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open the PowerShell by the administrator then  write this command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"